# How to remove the Yaxis values in Rechartjs without removing the catesian grid of Yaxis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

I tried using tick ={false} prop it removes both the cartesian line and y axis values.

Eg:

`<YAxis tickLine={false} axisLine={false} />`

Comment: For now I have used opacity={0} as a quick hack